# SRAM Red eTap on Ultegra bike

Tags: derailleur, sram

I own a 2018 Cannondale SuperSix EVO Ultegra. When I bought the bike I upgraded the crank set to the Cannondale Spider 52/36. I recently decided to go to SRAM Res eTap. During my install the FD is at the top end of the braze-on and it’s hitting the big chainring.

Is my best bet ordering a new set of chainrings at 50/34? Or is this bike not compatible?

Comment: Could you shim between the FD and the brazeon mount, to rotate the cage a little and remove the interference? You might be able to file the top of the slot in the braze on so the mech can be mounted higher.

Comment: Would be worth looking at a sram front mech and see if it effectively mounts higher than the ultegra one, but shifter compatibility may be an issue.

Comment: @Criggie: OP has to use the SRAM front derailleur since it’s electric (eTap). Incompatible to any other shifter system.

Comment: I was trying to avoid filing the braze on. Seems like it would be the cheapest option and I could keep the standard setup.

Comment: @JacobHoffpauir another option is to get a band-on adapter, but that assumes your seat tube is round, can take some compression (ie not carbon) and that it could either mount above the brazeon or you'd have to remove the braze on.  All messy.

Answer (score 1):

Cost aside, a carbon framebuilder or repairer could likely figure out a good way of doing it.

If tire clearance considerations allow, a simple way would be removing the existing hanger and building up the needed area to 31.8 or 34.9, then doing a hanger adapter. (If by some chance it's both a round tube and a standard diameter, you might not even need to build it up, but one or both of those probably isn't the case.) This would be a fabrication-minimal way. Or they might just bond on a new hanger. Or they might feel comfortable just relocating the holes for the existing hanger.

I would look askance at filing it unless it was clear that a good amount of material would remain. Weakening that spot too much could make terrible things happen. That said, if you tried it and it didn't work, you will almost certainly have outs, either from a third party or from Cannondale. I've known them to replace SuperX FD hangers as a paid repair and I assume they're able to do this frame as well.